# "Vectorize" a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I want to define a function that takes 2 Series and returns a Series. I could iterate over the elements of both Series, but that's tedious. I could use `np.vectorize()`, but is there a simpler way?

Here's a toy example (Python 3.7) and what I've tried:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "strs": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "bools": [True, False, False]
    })

def custom_func(strs, bools):
    return [s+s if b else None for s, b in zip(strs, bools)]

# This works, but it's tedious (and slower than vectorized stuff)
df["new_strs"] = custom_func(df["strs"], df["bools"])


def custom_func2(s, b):
    return s+s if b else None

# This works, but is there a simpler way I'm missing?
df["new_strs2"] = np.vectorize(custom_func2)(df["strs"], df["bools"])

# Neither of these work. Error message:
# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
# a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
#
# This one is what I'd call "simple"
df["new_strs2"] = custom_func2(df["strs"], df["bools"])
# This one isn't using vectorization but I tried it anyway
df["new_strs2"] = df["strs"].apply(custom_func2, args=df["bools"])
```

Here's how I'd do it in R:

```r
df = data.frame(
  strs = c("a", "b", "c"),
  bools = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
)

custom_func2 = function(s, b) if (b) paste0(s, s) else NA

df$strs2 = custom_func2(df$strs, df$bools)
```

Comment: Try `np.where` may be `def custom_func(strs, bools): return np.where(bools,strs+strs,np.nan)` and `custom_func(df['strs'],df['bools'])` ?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is **not** vectorized.

Comment: I think your trivial example is too trivial. In that case, I'd compute the result then go back and put the `None` values in afterwards. Maybe you need a more detailed example?

Comment: no,  according to [this doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), it is essentially a for loop. See the Note part.